# Changing the width of a menu item dynamically

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code:

```
<div class='menu'>
    <div class='menu_1'>
    <a href='../test.php'>JOBS</a>
    </div>
    <div class='menu_2'>
    <a href='../test.php'>EMPLOYERS</a>
    </div>
    <div class='menu_3'>
    <a href='../test.php'>MEMBERS</a>
    </div>
    <div class='menu_4'>
    <a href='../test.php'>CONTRACTORS</a>
    </div>
    <div class='menu_5'>
    <a href=../test.php'>REMINDERS</a>
    </div>
    <div class='menu_6'>
    <a href='../test.php'>REPORTS</a>
    </div>  
    </div>
```

I also have the following Jquery that will dynamically size the a links based on how many items are in the menu:

```
$('.menu a').css('width',100/$('.menu > div').size() + '%');
```

This code works the way I want it to, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this using only CSS?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried setting the a widths to auto and setting the div menu width to whatever you want for the whole size?

Comment: Yea, all that did for me was to scrunch everything up right next to each other.

Comment: Try setting `width:auto;` and then add padding and margins?

Comment: Don't forget to set margins or padding to separate them!

Comment: Can you post a fiddle that contains a working example for this?

Comment: man... I have a test to take in like 2 minutes.... here is a css menu that does just that but I have not been able to get it to work in IE http://jsfiddle.net/M8L6w/ (hence this not being an answer but a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get all the links on one line in a way that looks nice. The easiest way to do that is with tables, or with modern browsers, the table display types. Try this:

```
.menu { display: table-row; width: 100%; }
.menu > div { display: table-cell; }
```

You may need to add an extra div around the menu with `display: table`.

This won't do exactly what the jQuery does; links with larger text will take up more space. This is arguably better behavior as long as the table stretching algorithm is working OK.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried that, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set .menu to display:inline-block ( IE8+ only :-/ ) and a to display:block;

http://jsfiddle.net/6XDwx/